# How AppStore Connect validates binary after submission?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ipa

I am looking for some info about validation process of submitted ipa file. The one that happens right after upload via Application Loader is finished. I am developing a framework and while using it some apps get warnings from validation at that stage.

I am looking for any information whether is a string-based validation of binary contents or something more sophisticated. Are they launching the app or just scanning it somehow?

I believe that my implementation is correct but wanted to properly address this warnings.

Comment: What are the warnings?

Comment: @rmaddy push related. But actually in framework development I need to handle both situations where there are push enabled in the app or they are not.

Comment: The only people who can definitively answer are people who work or have worked at Apple, and they cannot legally answer. So what's the point of the question? All we can do is guess, and how would you know what guess is right?

Comment: @matt my point was that there are some folks, who go to conferences and talk to people who know people working at Apple or are ex-Apple, etc. I am not expecting the exact 'they validate that way or another' but rather bunch of rumours and expectations that may be somehow helpful :)